# what is best solution for managing heap size for node.js

Tags: node.js, bigdata, heap-memory, v8

We are going to analysis on twitter data so for this we will use node but the issue we are facing is that older versions of `v8 chrome engine` didn't provide heap size more than `1.9 gb` on 64 bit (Our colleagues did analysis on amazon data and they faced this problem and they overcame this problem using distributed computing but this is not a good solution).

How much heap size 64 bit V8 chrome engine officially giving us nowadays.

What is the best solution for it?

We have been searching for lot of articles and solutions over the internet. Is io.js suitable for such tasks?

Answer (score 0):

this will be a good effort from our side to debug the Heap Error. You may try one of these,

1. Try to figure out what is causing the heap error. It will be a timer going on continuous loop, or a loop that is executing for a long time - Reduce such cases
2. Add max_old_space_size=8192 to you start or build script
3. If you are using nginx / apache server, you can try increasing the memory